# SpringBoot3 filter requests based on a specific claims

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot-3

I'm using springboot v3.2.3 with the following dependencies

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Here my config

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I have this in applications.properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=<issuer-uri>
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.audiences=<app>
```

The jwt token verification works correctly (by allowing only the specified audience and the application uses the right issuer public certificate ). However, I want to filter based on other **claims**, like roles. what's the cleanest way to do so ?

Comment: You can use an authentication converter to turn "roles" claim into Spring "authorities". You can also access any attribute from the `Authentication` in Spring Security SpEL. You might have a look to [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication) (but pay more attention to the source, it seems that the README needs a refresh). It aims at building access control rules like `@PreAuthorize("is(#username) or hasAuthority('NICE') or onBehalfOf(#username).can('greet')")` (username and `NICE` role being in claims)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the claim names are slightly different ! the **scope** is under `app_scopes` claim  and the **role** is under the `app_roles` claim, that's why SpringSecurity didn't map correctly theses claims with the authorities !

[image]

Hence in order to configure the roles/scopes we have to use a custom jwt converter ( which converts the jwt token into an [authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) object )

```java
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@Component
public class JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = ((List<String>) jwt.getClaims().get("app_roles")).stream() 
                .map(roleName -> "ROLE_" + roleName)
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<GrantedAuthority> scopes = ((List<String>)jwt.getClaims().get("app_scopes")).stream()
                .map(scopeName -> "SCOPE_" + scopeName)
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(scopes);
        authorities.addAll(roles);
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Then we just need to wire the **JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter** with our SpringSecurity configuration  ([FilterChain](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html)

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter) {
        this.jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/test").access(AuthorizationManagers.allOf(
                                AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority("SCOPE_super"),
                                AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority("ROLE_adminit")
                        ))
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(customJwtAuthenticationConverter())));

        return http.build();
    }

    private JwtAuthenticationConverter customJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return converter;
    }

}
```

Now we are able to manage the authorization !
The user's token should have SCOPE_super and ROLE_adminit to be able to access to the `/test` -secured- endpoint

Obviously we can also use `@PreAuthorize` at the method level.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own `org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidator`, for example the custom `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtClaimValidator` for `roles` claim can be added as follows:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.*;

 @Bean
 public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
     NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuerUri);

     List<OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt>> validators = List.of(
             // add default validators
             JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuerUri), 
             // add custom validator for roles claim
             new JwtClaimValidator<>(
                        "roles",
                         predicateToValidateRoles)
             )
        );

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(validators));

        return jwtDecoder;
    }
```

Link to spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-validation-custom